# For what interval of $k$ does the equation have one postitive and one negative root?

Tags: calculus, quadratics, nonlinear-system

I was given an equation that looked like this

$(k-x)(1-x) + 4$

and was told to find the interval of k when the equation would have one positive root and one negative root.

So far I have found the solutions in terms of k

$x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(k+1-\sqrt{k^2-2k-15})$

$x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(k+1+\sqrt{k^2-2k-15})$

I am a bit stuck of where to go from here, do we have to figure it out using 
$\sqrt{b^2-4ac}$?

Comment: You want the two roots to be real (i.e. positive discriminant) and of opposite signs, which is to say their product to be negative (i.e. negative free term).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=(x-1)(x-k)+4=x^2-(k+1)x+(k+4)$. So $y=f(x)$ represents a parabola facing up (concave up). For the roots to be of opposite signs and real, we need 
$$f(0)<0 \quad \text{ and} \quad \text{discriminant } \geq 0.$$
Thus $k+4 < 0$ and $(k+1)^2-4(k+4)  \geq 0$. But the latter inequality is true if the first inequality holds. So $k <-4$.

Answer (score 1):

Expand your equation to get
$$x^2-(k+1)x+k+4=0$$

For this equation to have one positive and one negative root, the product of its roots is negative, thus
$$k+4<0$$

$$\therefore k < -4$$

---

You don't have to check $D=b^2-4ac$, since the product of roots of the quadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ is $c/a$, but since this value is negative, $ac$ is also negative, thus resulting in $D \geq 0$

Answer (score 1):

I made some silly errors
in my original answer.
The corrections now seem to show that
k < -4 is the condition.

Following dxiv's advice,
the roots are
$x_1 = \frac{1}{2}(-\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)+k+1)
$
and
$x_2 = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)+k+1)
$.

For there to be
two real roots,
we must have
$k^2-2k-15 > 0$
or
$k^2-2k+1 > 16$
or
$(k-1)^2 > 16
$
or
$k-1 > 4$
or
$k-1 < -4$
or
$k > 5$
or
$k < -3$.

(Error - had -5 here)

To make the roots
of different signs,
consider the cases separately.

If $k > 5$
then
$\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)+k+1 > 0$
so we want
$-\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)+k+1
\lt 0$
or
$\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)
\gt k+1
$
or
$k^2-2k-15
\gt k^2+2k+1
$
or
$0 > 4k+16$
which never happens.

(I messed up the inequality below
also)

If $k < -3$
then
$\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)+k+1 > 0$
so we want
$\sqrt(k^2-2k-15)
\gt -k-1
$
or
$k^2-2k-15
\gt k^2+2k+1
$
or
$0 > 4k+16$
or
$k <-4$,

Comment: Let $k=-5$. Then it seems that the roots are $-2\pm\sqrt{5}$ (according to your solution). One root is positive and the other is negative.

Comment: Thanks. I made a silly error - k-1 < -4 implies k < -3, not -5. I'll fix it.